# how to disable a trigger using hibernate

Tags: hibernate, database-trigger

i have entity `DisciplinaryProceedingCase` which has a trigger `(BEFORE INSERT)`called `dp_insert`

i want to **DISABLE** and **ENABLE** this trigger on bases of some conditions

so i did as follows

```
public boolean saveDisciplinaryProceedings(DisciplinaryProceedingCase disciplinaryProceedingCase) {

        boolean b=false;
        try {
            currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            currentSession.createQuery("ALTER TRIGGER dp_insert DISABLE");// using this query to disable
        currentSession.saveOrUpdate(disciplinaryProceedingCase);
        b=true;
        }
        catch (Exception e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return b;

    }
```

but it gives exception `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ALTER near line 1, column 1 [ALTER TRIGGER dp_insert DISABLE]`

please can any explain how to disable a trigger in hibernate .
**is it possible to do so ?**

Comment: Try: currentSession.createNativeQuery("ALTER TRIGGER dp_insert DISABLE")

Comment: `alter TRIGGER dp_insert DISABLE;` gives error in mysql work bench also like unexpected 'alter'

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. It's not possible to disable triggers in MySQL!

Comment: so sad to hear it. but how to achieve it ?

Comment: Why do you want to disable the trigger?

Comment: i do not want this before insert to be happened on some conditions so that i can execute another trigger on it . so i want to disable it and enable it grammatically in hibernate?

Comment: And why do you do this with a trigger? You could call a procedure instead

Comment: okay will check it. thank you.